# Rails: how can I force no value for a form_for text field for a model that has that field populated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I have this form:

```
=form_for @current_user, :url => update_password_path do |f|
    %label{:for => ""} * New Password
    =f.password_field :password, :value => ""
```

But when the current user has a password, this field is populated on the page despite the `:value => ""`

How can I force this field blank on the page and still use form_for?

Comment: Please tell me you're not storing plain-text passwords.  Or at least tell me what site you're developing so that I may never visit.

Comment: Haha no, I'm using authlogic. I think the fact that a password appears as the value is a browser caching problem because the value is "" in the rendered html.

Answer (score 1):

```
password_field_tag "user[password]", ""
```